# Windows Form being regarded as a "type, which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to teach myself the fundamentals of windows form applications using .net framework, and so I decided to pick the empty project template on visual studio 19 so I could practically learn what the auto generated code in a .net core app is all about and rely on nothing.

Anyway I made a form.cs file by adding a new "class" file for the form but in making my main method in the program.cs file the "Application.run" line generates an error as the "MainForm" is apparently "a type, which is not valid in the given context". I understand .net core is different from .net framework but I thought a lot of the windows form code would look the same from what I've seen. Sorry if this sounds stupid but I don't know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you're trying to *teach yourself the fundamentals of windows form applications using .net framework*, then use .Net Framework. Otherwise, teach yourself the fundamentals of .Net Core. BTW, which version of .Net Core? `3.0`? `3.1`? `5.0 Preview`? Something else? Maybe start with `.Net FW 4.8` instead.

Comment: Please show us your code. | Most likely you forgot the using(s). Generally the IDE's Programm Template will get you a working rump that you should use. As long as you do not modify the the designer create files, you can learn a lot just from reading what it writes. | But the core is just showing the first window and starting the Event Queue, wich is the basis of pretty much all GUI programming.

Answer (score -1):

**Welcome to StackOverflow**

You <s>might be</s> *are* missing the `new` and the brackets.

Write
`Application.Run(new myForm());`

instead of 
`Application.Run(myForm);`

What the first line is doing is creating an object of the form `myForm` and passing it as parameter to the `Application.Run(...)` function.

2nd Line will give a compile time error (the one that you are getting)

---

*Gyaan*

The `Run` function of `Application` class requires an object of the form, which is created when you call the `new` operator on your form class (`myForm` in above code)

The type name (form class name without `new` being called) is used when you want to specify another object of that class type. For example:
`myForm frm1;`

Here, the variable `frm1` is created in stack and is specified to be of type `myForm`.
When you initialize this variable, you will need it to assign to an object. The object is created by calling the `new` operator on the class:
`new myForm()`

The above line creates an object of type `myForm` in the heap.
To use this object, you need a variable that can point to this object (reference in C# and pointer in C/C++). For that, you can combine the two codes in 2 lines or 1 line as shown below

2 Lines Code:

```
myForm frm1;`
frm1 = new myForm();
```

1 Line Code

`myForm1 frm1 = new myForm();`

Now when you write code like

`frm1.Title = "My Form Title";`

This will change the value of `Title` property of the object created in heap.